# tinymce resizing with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, rte

Here is the code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    plugins: "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing: true,
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,

    skin: "o2k7",
    skin_variant: "silver",

    content_css: "css/example.css",

    template_external_list_url: "js/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url: "js/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url: "js/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url: "js/media_list.js",

});
```

The user can resize it with mouse. However, after refreshing the page, I want the tinymce to have a fixed size, not the one that the user gave it. How to give it fixed size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try add this line of code to tinyMCE config

```
theme_advanced_resizing_use_cookie : true
```

Comment: Actually it's supposed to be set to false in my case :) Tnx